# Why don't I create Amazon lightsailclient and set up UserData?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Why don't I create Amazon lightsailclient and set up UserData?

```
var shuju = new CreateInstancesRequest()
            {
                BlueprintId = "centos_7_1901_01",
                BundleId = "micro_2_0",
                AvailabilityZone = "ap-northeast-1d",
                InstanceNames = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>() { "test" },
                UserData = "echo root:test123456- |sudo chpasswd root\r\nsudo sed -i 's/^#\\?PermitRootLogin.*/PermitRootLogin yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config;\r\nsudo sed -i 's/^#\\?PasswordAuthentication.*/PasswordAuthentication yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config;\r\nsudo reboot\r\n"
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to run a User Data script on a Linux instance, then the first line must begin with `#!`.

It uses the same technique as an Amazon EC2 instance, so see: [Running Commands on Your Linux Instance at Launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)